# Как удалить элемент по ссылке на него?

Tags: php

Задача заключается в обходе дерева. Для этих целей использую рекурсию. Теперь нужно по условию удалить элемент по его ссылке.

```
class Test {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->test1 = [
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => [
                'd' => [
                    'e' => 'test'
                ],
            ],
            'c' => null,
            'd' => (object)[
                'e' => 'test',
            ],
            'f' => (object)[
                'test' => 'a',
                'e' => (object)[
                    'test' => 'test',
                ],
            ]
        ];

        $this->test2 = [
            'e' => 'test',
        ];

        $this->test3 = 'test';

        $this->checkTypeRecursive($this->test1);
        $this->checkTypeRecursive($this->test2);
        $this->checkTypeRecursive($this->test3);
    }

    public function checkTypeRecursive(&$values) {
        if (is_array($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                $this->checkTypeRecursive($values[$key]);
            }
        } elseif (is_object($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                $this->checkTypeRecursive($values->$key);
            }
        } else {
            if ($values == 'test') {
                //Присвоение по ссылке работает.
                $values = 'Привет';

                /** А как удалить элемент на который эта ссылка получена */
                //unset($values); //Так не сработает ибо это значение.

                /**
                 * Остальная логика
                 * ....
                 */
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r(new Test());
```

Comment: Зачем? вам по ссылке передовать `value`? если надо получить результат то верните его или как хороший вариант выкинуть exception что бы наверняка остановить рекурсию и не мучаться с return'ами

Comment: Мне не нужно прерывать рекурсию или возвращать результат. А обработать всё дерево. Нужно его обойти и удалить из него все элементы, которые не удовлетворяют множество условий. Я упростил код и добавил комментарий в коде `Остальная логика ` не просто так

Comment: ну так вы значение обрабатываете делайте unset в массиве. Передаём в функцию `$key` и делаем `unset($values[$key])`

Comment: Хотя тогда как быть с test3, у него же нет ключа -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть метод рекурсии возвращает true если переданное ему значение соответствует твоему условию, в таком случае проверяем что он возвратил и если true удаляем элемент функцией [unset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php).

```
class Test {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->test1 = [
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => [
                'd' => [
                    'e' => 'test'
                ],
            ],
            'c' => null,
            'd' => (object)[
                'e' => 'test',
            ],
            'f' => (object)[
                'test' => 'a',
                'e' => (object)[
                    'test' => 'test',
                ],
            ]
        ];

        $this->test2 = [
            'e' => 'test',
        ];

        $this->test3 = 'test';

        $this->checkTypeRecursive($this);
    }

    public function checkTypeRecursive(&$values) {

        if (is_array($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                if ($this->checkTypeRecursive($values[$key]))
                    unset($values[$key]);
            }
        } elseif (is_object($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                if ($this->checkTypeRecursive($values->$key))
                    unset($values->$key);
            }
        } else {
            if ($values == 'test')
                return true;
        }
    }
}

print_r(new Test());
```

https://repl.it/CmJR/1

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте ссылку на онлайн-интерпретаторы/компиляторы. https://repl.it/CmJR/0

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, добавил

Comment: Cпасибо. Помогло. Хотя столкнулся с еще одной трудностью в тестах
`$this->test5 = (object)['test'];` Крайне странно поведение

Comment: Что-то не так с конвертацией массива с числовыми индексами в объект, например так $this->test5 = (object)['x' => 'test']; работает нормально.